# how do i access my token in passport-google

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-google-oauth

i'm trying to use passport-google  this is my post request

```
app.post('/auth/google', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {code } = req.body;
        console.log(code)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving code:', error);
    }
});
```

this is my response

```
4/0AbUR2VP-VgZE5PP3lm46kiJcAzAuOOJlxAAt2Bm7NRP9IPw3LDOn0rwYHb2r06NJ-KZJpw
```

how can i access my token in this route in order for google to verify the token and authenticate the user

```
app.get( '/auth/callback',
  passport.authenticate( 'google', {
  })
);
```